# Count average value inside dll for many items

Tags: c++, lua, average

I create dll written in C++. Main script is written in Lua. 
Inside dll there is a function:

```
static int OnQuote(lua_State* L) {
//receives parameter called "last_price" and try to count average price
return 0;
}
```

It receives "last_price" for 5 stocks, trading on stock exchange. I want to count average "last_price" per 100 last deals that come in this function. 
Each paper count its own average price separetly from each other.
Examples of papers: "SBER", "GAZP", "ROSN", "GMKN", "MGNT"
What is the best way to do it?
Which container should I use to store data? May be map with vectors?
Where to declare global map?

I created map inside DllMain, but it is not visible inside function OnQuote:

```
map <string, vector <int> > avr;
avr.insert(pair<string, vector<int> >("SBER", vector<int>{}));
avr.insert(pair<string, vector<int> >("GAZP", vector<int>{}));
avr.insert(pair<string, vector<int> >("GMKN", vector<int>{}));
avr.insert(pair<string, vector<int> >("MGNT", vector<int>{}));
avr.insert(pair<string, vector<int> >("ROSN", vector<int>{}));
```

I try to store intermediate data inside vectors.
Help me please with strategic view to this task.

Comment: One question per question please!

Comment: Do not share global variables from shared libraries, that causes all kinds of weird problems.

Comment: I dont no how to do it without globals

Comment: As mentioned you shouldn't anyways.